# Android - Error when importing OneSignal Library in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, onesignal

i try to integrate **OneSignal** to my existing Android App, but after insert just one line :

```
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
```

and then do sync, i got this error :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':processFlavorDebugManifest'.
>
> > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

any idea to solve this ?

Note :

- I am using **Android Studio 2.3**

Comment: Post your Android Mainifest file

Comment: okay, wait a minute...

Comment: _Manifest merger failed with multiple errors_  Post those errors also

Comment: Have u added this in Gradle android {
   defaultConfig {
      manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "PUT YOUR ONESIGNAL APP ID HERE",
                              // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                              onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
 }

Comment: oh no i forgot, thanks...now it worked!!!

Comment: See https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/troubleshooting-android#section-error-execution-failed-for-task-app-processdebugmanifest-

Comment: @RahulGiradkar is right. This is the solution.